# Hadoop 's java environment-variables dosen't change?

Tags: java, hadoop, environment-variables

I worked with **HADOOP** as a single node in  ubuntu , the java  home was set to java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre .

Now i've changed in ***bashrc*** my java home to point to jdk-1.8.0 (since i need it to point to jdk and not jre for other projects).

When i run `hadoop fs -ls` i get this error :

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 166: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

anyone knows how to fix that ?

this is my bashrc file :

```
 case $- in
    *i*) ;;
     *) return;;
  esac


 HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth


 shopt -s histappend


HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

  [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

  if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
   debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
  fi


 case "$TERM" in
xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
 esac



if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then

    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
   fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt


case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
;;
*)
;;
esac


if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'


 if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  . ~/.bash_aliases
 fi

 if ! shopt -oq posix; then
 if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
 elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
 fi
 fi
#HADOOP VARIABLES START

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL 
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"

#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

Comment: show me your bashrc file because after installation hadoop fs -ls is the basic command to list all files.

Comment: @Shriram i've updated my question :i've deleted the comments from the bashrc

Comment: stupid question but have you jsut done a ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre//bin/java ?

Comment: no i just typed hadoop fs -ls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem :

we must change in `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` as well the Java_home:

```
# set to the root of your Java installation
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181
```